# test content of EditText with regular expression

Tags: android

Please I want that an  EditText be composed of two letters and five digits.
I thought to use regular expressions., but I do not understand how to use it.
thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to validate that the input is like this, how to not allow the input to be in any other format, or something else?

Comment: yes , I want to validate the  input to be like  this form.

Comment: @hajerBCH means it should have 7 characters  and among them 2 letter and 5 digits right

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean validate(String str){
    int letters = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int others = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char ch = str.getAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
            letters++;
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(ch)){
            numbers++;
        }
        else{
            others++;
        }
    }
    return others == 0 && numbers==5 && letters == 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank Gabe , but i I do not see the use of regular expression .I mean like I find  this structure : final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}");, so my problem how to use it . i hope  you understand me.

Comment: This isn't a good problem to use regular expressions on.  Nothing that involves counting is.  Regular expressions match patterns, but they don't have any other brains.  Unless the 2 letters and 5 numbers appear in a certain order, such as llnnnnn or nnllnnn or something of the sort-  then you have a trivial pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);


  edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {            
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                              int before, int count) {
    char[] c_arr = s.toCharArray();
    int letterCount=0;
    int digitCount=0;

        for(Character c : c_arr){

            try{
                Integer.parseInt(c.toString())
                digitCount++;
                if(digitCount > 2){
                    // alert here
                    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
                    EditText edit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                    edit.setText(s);
                    break;
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                letterCount++;
                if(letterCount > 5){
                    // alert here
                    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
                    EditText edit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                    edit.setText(s);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
  });
```

Comment: KEYSAN please , i have some problem , when i make for example "LM12345", the program is bocked , Knowing that i have to make p2.putExtra("tva", tva.getText().toString()); that i wonder where can I make it.